# Java Regex, extract 2nd statement

Tags: java, regex

I have this situation, I want to extract the statement1 of that string expression, but I'm not an expert in regex.

```
String expression = "blabla if(x = 6, statement1, statement2) blabla";
```

but statement1 can be recursively another if expression, like:

```
String expression = "blablaba iF(X = 6, if(X = 3, Z, Y), Y) bablabla";
```

in this case I need to extract `Z`, or at least `if(X = 3, Z, Y)`

I made that:

```
String IF_CONDITION_PATTERN = "[\\s|\\n|\\t]if\\s*\\((.*)\\,(.*)\\,(.*)([^)]*?)";

String formulaStr = "blablaba iF(X = 6, if(X = 3, Z, Y), Y) bablabla";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(IF_CONDITION_PATTERN,
           Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(formulaStr);

while (matcher.find()) {
     for(int i=0; i<matcher.groupCount();i++){
           System.out.println("Found " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i) + ".");
        }
    }
```

The result is:

```
Found 0:  iF(X = 6, if(X = 3, Z, Y), Y) bablabla.
Found 1: X = 6, if(X = 3, Z.
Found 2:  Y).
Found 3:  Y) bablabla.
```

Can someone help me at least extracting the statement1 `if(X = 3, Z, Y)`.

Thanks,
Nuno

Comment: Regex cannot handle recursive expressions. At least not in Java. You'll need a proper parser for that.

Comment: I know that, but what I'm asking for is to have some regex that can extract the statement1, in this case is 
if(X = 3, Z, Y)

Comment: Well, if it can't parse recursive expressions, how does it know when the internal expression ends? What if instead of `Z` you have another `if`? You said it's recursive. Therefore it cannot be parsed with a regex. Therefore a regex cannot match the part that you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try if regex below works for you, it will match `statement1` and `Z` for your example.

The regex just look for if statement then match the 2nd argument which don't contains `,` inside

`\bif\([^,]+,\s?([^,]+),[^,]+\)`

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/qk8CVQ/1)

Comment: Thanks a lot, for me it's enough.